# Report Parameters in Report Builder 1.0 - Drop-Down Lists Not Appearing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reportbuilder

I've been playing with Microsoft Report Builder 1.0 recently as we were asked to create an ad-hoc reporting model for some of our users to create their own reports.

When adding filters to reports the application has always provided drop-down lists of available values for each condition I select, however, this only seems to be the case when running the Report Builder on my own PC building reports over a database on my local SQL Server.

When I try accessing a remote database from my Report Builder, or when I access my own database from someone else's PC, the drop-down lists are not generated, meaning the user has to manually enter text values into the parameter fields.

Has anyone else had this problem or found a way around it?  Is this behaviour intentional, maybe for performance or security reasons?  It seems a bit odd that this would be the case, but stranger things have happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem, there were 2 reasons I saw it happening.

1. The datasource to the report model was not set to use Windows Integrated Security.  I have found that if it's set to anything else the drop-downs don't work.
2. There were database permission issues on the tables/views that the Models were using.  I ended up reworking the models to use views that our end users had permissions to, instead of using the restricted tables.

I have found Report Builder 1.0 and 2005 Models to be fickle and difficult to use and maintain and very limited in functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look at the datasource properties, I'm pretty sure they're using a service account to access the database, which is probably why it's not working.  I agree though, I'm not overly impressed with Report Builder 1.0 and the 2005 Report Models so far, it all feels a bit of a hassle for what you actually get out of it.